# Qual è il significato di "risparmiarsi il sapone" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> «Bene, – mi dissi quel giorno, perché prima di muovere un passo una ragione devi pure trovarla e far ridere non piace a nessuno – se il tuo mestiere è interessarti di tutti, comincia intanto a interessarti di uno: non di piú che uno solo. Fino in fondo però, fino alla radice a dir poco. Non c’è mezzo migliore cosí per interessarsi sul serio anche di tutti quegli altri. Se no, galantuomo, **risparmiati pure il sapone**: tutto il resto non è che paesaggio».

Non riesco a capire il significato dell'espressione "risparmiarsi il sapone" in questo brano. Non sembra che si trovi nulla al riguardo nella voce "sapone" dei dizionari. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Sembra qualcosa che ha a che fare con il mestiere o l'atteggiamento della persona a cui è rivolta questa sprezzante critica. Chi è o che atteggiamento ha?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Si tratta del prete del paesino dove si svolge il racconto.

Comment: Allora mi viene in mente che l'interlocutore lo sta accusando di limitarsi a dare una "lavata" alle anime delle persone (con la confessione?) senza realmente ascoltarli o interessarsi ai problemi di questi.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Veramente non c'è nessun interlocutore. Questo prete è la voce narrante del racconto e in questo caso si tratta di una riflessione che si fa a lui stesso.

Comment: OK ma credo che il significato sia lo stesso. il "sapone" di cui si parla è metaforico. Indica appunto un "lavaggio" superficiale dell'anima delle persone, anziché un reale interessamento a queste. Questa è la mia interpretazione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il detto "**[dare il sapone](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/S/sapone.shtml)**" vuo dire *adulare, lusingare, rendere più malleabile qualcuno.* Il sapone, molto scivoloso, richiama l'idea di azioni sfuggenti, insinuanti (cfr Treccani alla [voce sapone 2a](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sapone/)).

**Risparmiare il sapone** in questo contesto vuol dire *risparmiare il sapone (in senso figurato) che si potrebbe usare per "dare il sapone"*, ossia *risparmiare la fatica di interessarsi degli altri* se si fallisce cominciando a interessarsi di uno "non di piú che uno solo. Fino in fondo però, fino alla radice a dir poco.  Non c’è mezzo migliore cosí per interessarsi sul serio anche di tutti quegli altri. Se no, galantuomo, risparmiati pure il sapone.."